# No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'locationCode' {originalText=locationCode}

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a simple project using Hibernate

I  have the following classes  :

Model :

```
public class InputHStock implements Serializable {

private long hsID;
private String locationCode ; 
private String itemCode;
private int stock;
```

DAO :

```
public class InputHStockDAO {
public List<InputHStock> getAllIHS() {
    List<InputHStock> ihs = new ArrayList<InputHStock>();
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        trns = session.beginTransaction();
        ihs = session.createQuery("select locationCode ").list();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return ihs;
}
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="Myfactory">
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">testSQL</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">testpwd1</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<mapping resource="InputHStock.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="InputHStock" table="POC_HEALTHYSTOCK">
  <id name="hsID"  column="ID" type="int">
     <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="locationCode" column="LOCATIONCODE" type="string"/>
  <property name="itemCode" column="ITEMCODE" type="string"/>
  <property name="stock" column="STOCK" type="int"/>
  </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

However When I run the project I have the following error :

**No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'locationCode' {originalText=locationCode}**

Any ideas ?